# Is it possible to run Android Studion on Windows 11 and use adb in WSL2?

Tags: android-studio, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Android Studio with a virtual device, all in Windows 11. (192.168.10.10)

In th other hand I have WSL with Kali Linux. (172.0.10.10)

Im wondering if I can see this virtual device from WSL, the problem is that they are not in the same IP Range, so they don't see each other.

I think that if I can configure the WSL to be in the same network as Windows, I would be able to see the phone. (From 172.0.10.10 -> 192.168.10.10)

Or vice versa, the phone in the same network as WSL (From 192.168.10.10 -> 172.0.10.10)

Comment: You should edit your question and describe in detail what is running where (Windows, inside WSL). At it's current state your question misses a lot of details so answers are unlikely.